# Prática de deploy, como fazer?

Tags: php

Atualmente  muitas linguagem possuem práticas de *deploy* que automatiza todo o processo, conceito como CI (*Continuous Integration*).

A cada *commit* no repositório é sistema de *deploy* (acredito que o Jenkins ou Capistrano) executa os teste unitário/TDD e se tudo estiver ok ele faz o envio dos arquivos para o servidor.

Minhas duvida é de como é feito o *deploy* para aplicações em PHP e quais ferramentas são usadas para isso ?

Jenkins e Capistrano. São usados geralmente em Ruby. O Jenkins permite executar teste unitários ou qualquer outros testes e se tudo passar  faz o *deploy* para o servidor. Quem faz o gerenciamento *deploy* no servidor é o Capistrano, ele mantém os arquivos da ultima *release* que estava funcionando corretamente e cria um link simbólico para a nova *release* que foi subido e se caso ocorra alguma falha na nova *release* o Capistrano volta apontar para o *release* anterior.

Quero entender como usar o Jenkins e o Capistrano para aplicações em PHP ou ferramentas parecidas.

Comment: Alguma das respostas satisfez sua duvida? se sim aceite uma das respostas ou explique algum ponto não satisfeito pelas respostas.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi o que você quer exatamente, mas há duas ferramentas para isto

1. **Simple PHP Git deploy script**:

   Automaticamente faz o deploy do código usando PHP e Git.

   - Repositorio: https://github.com/markomarkovic/simple-php-git-deploy
   - (este passo é somente necessário em repositorios privativos) vá para https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/settings/keys e adicione o sua chave SSH do servidor.
   - Va até https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/settings/hooks.
   - Clique em adicionar webhook no painel Webhooks.
   - Entre com a url do Payload para fazer o deploy do script ex: `http://example.com/deploy.php?sat=YourSecretAccessTokenFromDeployFile`.
2. **Deployer**

   - Download: http://deployer.org
   - Documentação: http://deployer.org/docs
3. Conforme o autor solicitou Jekins para PHP

   - Jenkins para PHP: http://jenkins-php.org

     <sub>Requerimentos: PHPUnit, PHP_CodeSniffer, PHPLOC, PHP_Depend, PHPMD, PHPCPD e phpDox</sub>

> **Nota:** Pelo que li sobre, você pode sim fazer o deploy de aplicativos PHP com ele, praticamente da mesma maneira que faz com aplicativos escritos em Ruby.

Comment: interessante o deployer. Vc já usou o jenkins e capistrano. São usados geralmente em Ruby. O jenkins permite executar teste unitários ou qualquer outros testes e se tudo passar  faz o deploy para o servidor. Quem faz o gerenciamento deploy no servidor é o capistrano, ele mantém os arquivos da ultima release que estava funcionando corretamente e cria um link simbólico para a nova release que foi subido e se caso ocorra alguma falha na nova release o capistrano volta apontar p o release anterior.

Comment: @LeandroMacedo Não, sou mais do tipo que faço as tarefas na mão. Mas um dia quem sabe eu testo.

Comment: ferramentas de automatizações são uma mão na roda. Ainda mias com os de devOps e CI. Recomendo que aprenda e muito interessante.

Comment: de curiosidade, que tipo de teste vc costuma fazer para sua aplicações ?

Comment: @LeandroMacedo Eu realmente faço muitas coisas na mão, eu sou muito focado no desenvolvimento de Classes/códigos para uso de outras ferramentas e não "soluções completas", mas vou estudar isto quando tiver um tempo :) ... Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Há um artigo em inglês explicando como deploy é feito com o `Git` [Artigo em inglês](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto), versão em português editada [Traduzida e Editada](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/automatizando-a-instalacao-deploy-e-atualizacao-de-sites-com-git/)

Trecho do artigo:
Repositório local
Se você já possui um repositório local, pule para o pŕoximo passo.
Tudo começa com a criação de um repositório Git simples:
Ferramentas utilizadas durante o processo:

```
$ mkdir website && cd website
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/thiagobelem/website/.git/
$ echo 'Olá, mundo!' > index.html
$ git add index.html
$ git commit -q -m "Iniciando o repositório"
```

Agora que seu repositório local está pronto, o index.html foi criado e o primeiro commit feito, vamos criar o repositório remoto no ambiente de produção (servidor onde o site está/vai rodar).
Repositório remoto
Partindo do princípio que o seu site vai rodar em um servidor que você possui acesso SSH facilitado, vamos criar o repositório lá que será uma cópia do servidor local:

```
$ mkdir website.git && cd website.git
$ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/thiagobelem/website.git/
```

Agora vamos começar a criar o git-hook que será responsável por copiar todos os arquivos - do repositório bare - para a pasta onde o site vai rodar, no ambiente de produção:

```
$ cat > hooks/post-receive
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/meusite.com.br git checkout -f
$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

Veja que primeiro definimos a variável de ambiente GIT_WORK_TREE como a raíz do site e depois executamos um git checkout -f que irá mover os arquivos sem nenhum vestígio do seu repositório Git.
Agora é só voltar para a sua máquina e adicionar o repositório remoto:

```
$ git remote add web ssh://meusite.com.br/home/thiagobelem/website.git
$ git push web +master:refs/heads/master
```

Atualizando os arquivos
À medida que você for trabalhando no site e quiser atualizar o servidor no ar, é so rodar o comando (após fazer o commit):

```
git push web
```

> Como o foco mudou para o jenkins deixarei alguns links de Tutoriais de utilização do PHP com o Jenkins como complemento.

- [SlideShare PHP com Jenkins](http://pt.slideshare.net/gpupo/integracao-continua-em-php-com-lenkins)
- http://jenkins-php.org/
- [Integrado com outras ferramento como Composer](http://www.sitepoint.com/preparing-building-php-project-jenkins/)
- [Instalação e configuração](http://duodra.co/2012/02/28/instalacao-do-jenkins-e-phing-para-projetos-php/)
- [Instalação e configuração Tutorial Americano](http://kogentadono.com/2013/05/06/ci-with-jenkins-and-php-part-1-installing-the-php-tools-and-jenkins/)

**Git**

- Link para download: http://git-scm.com/

**Deployer**

- Link para download: http://deployer.org/

**Heroku**

- Link de Acesso: https://www.heroku.com/

Comment: interessante o deployer. Vc já usou o jenkins e capistrano. São usados geralmente em Ruby. O jenkins permite executar teste unitários ou qualquer outros testes e se tudo passar  faz o deploy para o servidor. Quem faz o gerenciamento deploy no servidor é o capistrano, ele mantém os arquivos da ultima release que estava funcionando corretamente e cria um link simbólico para a nova release que foi subido e se caso ocorra alguma falha na nova release o capistrano volta apontar p o release anterior.

Comment: @LeandroMacedo, conhecia o `Jenkins` (usado em um projeto java feito na faculdade) mas estou conhecendo agora este `Capistrano`

Comment: vi a utilização do Capistrano para aplicações web em Ruby, e de cara me apaixonei. É muito prático e auxilia mto no deploy. Inclusive evite aqla situação de quando estamos subindo novos arquivos do sistema e ele fica inatendível.